# SQL Server pivot and error

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I keep getting an error from my query. I have no idea why.

Here the error message.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near '10'.

And here is my code:

```
DECLARE @Week VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT @StartDate =  MAX(S0.PostDate) FROM OWOR S0 WHERE S0.PostDate = '20151010'
SELECT @EndDate = MAX(S1.PostDate) FROM OWOR S1 WHERE S1.PostDate = '20160108' 

SET @Week = ''
SELECT @Week = @Week + '[' + [Week] + '],'
FROM 
    (SELECT 
    DISTINCT(DATENAME(MONTH, T2.PostDate) + ' (Week ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, T2.PostDate), 0)), 0), T2.PostDate) + 1) + ')') AS 'Week'
    ,LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, T2.PostDate, 112),6) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, T2.PostDate), 0)), 0), T2.PostDate) + 1) AS MonthNo 
    FROM WOR1 T0
    LEFT JOIN OWOR T2 ON T0.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
    WHERE T2.PostDate >= @StartDate AND T2.PostDate <= @EndDate) A
ORDER BY A.MonthNo
--SET @Week = LEFT(@Week, LEN(@Week) - 1)

EXEC ('SELECT *  
FROM (SELECT 
    DISTINCT(DATENAME(MONTH, T2.PostDate) + '' (Week '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, T2.PostDate), 0)), 0), T2.PostDate) + 1) + '')'') AS ''Week'',
    T0.ItemCode AS ''Item Code'',
    T1.ItemName AS ''Item Name'',
    CASE 
        WHEN T0.IssuedQty <= 0 THEN T0.PlannedQty 
        ELSE T0.IssuedQty
    END AS ''Quantity''
    FROM WOR1 T0
    LEFT JOIN OITM T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
    LEFT JOIN OWOR T2 ON T0.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
    WHERE T2.PostDate >= '+ @StartDate +' AND T2.PostDate <= '+ @EndDate +') B
PIVOT (SUM(Quantity) FOR [Week] IN ('+@Week+')) AS PVT')
```

Comment: Why is `--SET @Week = LEFT(@Week, LEN(@Week) - 1)` commented out? It seems necessary to remove the comma.

Comment: That's right. remove the comma. do you see anything wrong in my query?

Comment: Uh, well, the comma is the reason for the error you're getting.  If you remove it, it should be fine. If it still isn't working, post the new error... But your current error is caused by the comma not being removed from the `@Week` string.

Comment: Why don't you `PRINT` the SQL you use in `EXEC(...)` and show us that?